# Jquery: Div is hidding when .mouseup the browser's scrollbar

Tags: jquery, html, scrollbar, hide, mouseup

I have a function which close (hide) a div when clicking out of it (mouseup), and it works fine but the problem is:  when I (mouseup) the browser's scrollbar that div get closed (hidden)  too and I need it visible. in conclusion I need to hide that div when .mouseup all the body except the div itself and the browser's scroll bar.

here my function.

```
//close the windows-wrapper, blackout effect, and #close
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var contain = $(".loadiv .windows-wrapper");

    if (!contain.is(e.target) 
        && contain.has(e.target).length === 0)
    {
        contain.fadeOut("fast");
        $('#blackout').fadeOut("fast");
        $('#close').fadeOut("fast");
    }
});
```

Comment: Post your HTML/CSS and, ideally, make a http://www.jsfiddle.net. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Use

```
$('body')...
```

Instead of

```
$(document)...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YFmu9/4/

Generally, there's no difference between the document keyword an body selector. But you've managed to find one that I didn't know about. Thanks for the interesting question!

Complete answer:

```
$('body').mouseup(function (e)
{
    var contain = $(".loadiv .windows-wrapper");

    if (!contain.is(e.target) 
        && contain.has(e.target).length === 0)
    {
        contain.fadeOut("fast");
        $('#blackout').fadeOut("fast");
        $('#close').fadeOut("fast");
    }
});
```